# Why lambda expressions in Java 8 requires variables used inside it to use "final" modifier, but not when using method reference?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, closures, method-reference

Consider following class:

```
class Foo<T> {

    void handle(T t) {
        System.out.println("handling " + t);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);

        Foo<Integer> f = new Foo<>();

        list.forEach(f::handle);             // compiles fine
        //list.forEach(obj -> f.handle(obj));// compilation error

        f = new Foo<>(); // reassign f

    }
}
```

Why do I get compilation error for `obj -> f.handle(obj)`, but not for `f::handle`?

Comment: Um, both versions _should_ work without the `final` modifier.  (It still has to be effectively final, though.)

Comment: Yes, the question was why the second version does not require the final modifier.

Comment: _Neither_ version should require the final.

Comment: Do you assign new value to `s` after `forEach` call?

Comment: @MateusViccari I tried to simplify your question. Feel free to rollback my edit if you don't feel that it is what you wanted to ask.

Comment: I like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053161/94687 accepted answer there to a similar question more because it is a bit more detailed and clear. Although that question is more recent (young), and this one is older.So, if closing duplicates, this one should survive according to its age.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are two different constructs that are doing two different things. In the first case, you are getting the method reference of a specific object: this needs to be done only once, after which the JVM has its own reference (so effectively final) to the object `f` and can call the `handle` method. In the second case, at each call the JVM has to resolve the `f` reference and it thus complains that `f` must be `final`. You could easily write code that sets `f` to `null` while the `forEach` is running and thus cause a NPE.

Comment: I made a little example which might highlight the difference between lambda expression and method reference: http://pastebin.com/4W0ivi7U

Comment: You could also write `final Foo<Integer> f = null;` and cause a NPE. That doesn't explain why `f` has to be effectively final.

Comment: Some guy just changed my entire question, so i don't know if you're talking about "his" question or mine. But i think i got your point, thanks.

Comment: @MateusViccari I'm the "some guy". Sorry if I changed your question too much, was trying to prevent it from being closed as "unclear what you are asking" by posting example which would let us easily *reproduce* your problem. If I misunderstood problem you are facing consider posting another question, but this time provide more info with code which will let others reproduce error described in question.

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes you could, but from the compiler's perspective, the important is that the reference does not change and thus the program has a more deterministic behavior. The compiler won't stop you from willingly shooting yourself in the foot! :)

Answer (score 3):

To add an illustration to Giovanni's answer, we can highlight the difference between `f::handle` and `obj -> f.handle(obj)` if we replace `f` with a method call:

```
static Set<String> f() {
    System.out.println("  f() called");
    return new HashSet<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> empty = Collections.emptyList();
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");

    System.out.println("method reference, no invocations");
    empty.forEach(f()::add);

    System.out.println("method reference, 2 invocations");
    strings.forEach(f()::add);

    System.out.println("lambda, no invocations");
    empty.forEach(str -> f().add(str));

    System.out.println("lambda, 2 invocations");
    strings.forEach(str -> f().add(str));
}
```

Output:

```
method reference, no invocations
  f() called
method reference, 2 invocations
  f() called
lambda, no invocations
lambda, 2 invocations
  f() called
  f() called
```

So, as you see `.forEach(f()::add)` will evaluate `f()` right away and then call `add(...)` on the result as many times as the lambda is called.

On the other hand, `str -> f().add(str)` will not do anything upfront but will call f() every time the lambda is invoked.