# Function pointer to String method in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I don't understand a couple of things with lambda.

```
String s = "Hello World";       
Function<Integer, String> f = s::substring;
s = null;
System.out.println(f.apply(5));
```

Why is the `f.apply` method still working if `s = null`. After all, the `String` object should be deleted by the GC because there is no pointer that points to the object.

One more thing, why don't I need a return statement here?

```
Function<Integer, String> f = t -> t + "";
```

Comment: There absolutely is a pointer to the object.  `f` becomes an object which contains a pointer to `"Hello world"`.  `a::foo` evaluates `a` and stores a reference to its result.

Comment: As a side issue, `s`'s initial referent exists in the string constant pool and thus will never be garbage collected (unless the containing class is)

Comment: Try to ask only **one** question per question.

Comment: For the first question, also see [Why can method reference use non-final variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052917/why-can-method-reference-use-non-final-variables)

Comment: @LouisWasserman "Avoid answering questions in comments". Currently this question is on HNQ and the comment has 3 upvotes, that (will definitely) cause false impression on visitors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [JLS, Section 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) describes the runtime evaluation of method references.

> *The timing of method reference expression evaluation is more complex than that of lambda expressions (§15.27.4). When a method reference expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the :: separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. The **result of evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional interface type is invoked; at that point, the result is used as the target reference for the invocation**. This means the expression preceding the :: separator is evaluated only when the program encounters the method reference expression, and is not re-evaluated on subsequent invocations on the functional interface type.*

(bold emphasis mine)

Basically the reference to `s` as it is for the method reference is stored for later execution.  Here, the string `"Hello World"` is saved for later execution of the method reference.  Because of this, even if you set `s` to `null` after the declaration of the method reference, but before you execute the `Function`, it will still use the string `"Hello World"`.

Setting something to `null` does not guarantee that the garbage collector will collect it, and it won't guarantee that it's collected immediately.

Also, here, there still is a reference in the method reference, so it won't get garbage collected at all here.

Finally, lambda expression bodies have 2 forms: an expression and a block of statements with (possibly) a return statement.  With

```
Function<Integer, String> f = t -> t + "";
```

That is an expression.  The block statement equivalent would be:

```
Function<Integer, String> f = t -> { return t + "";};
```

Comment: In my example JLS means that f is envocing the method and saving the result and when I using the get function he returns me the ruslt. You say that becuase of f is a reference to the method so the object ("Hello World") is still stored in the memory, you say one thing and he say other thing or I didn't understand?

Comment: I don't know what example in the JLS you're referring to, but Java does not invoke the method (here, `substring`) when it encounters the method reference.  It will invoke it later when the functional method is invoked, here, `apply`.

Comment: So you are saying that java will save the object (here String) becuase of the pointer to the method (here substring)?

Comment: Yes.  When the method reference is encountered, `s` is evaluated and a separate reference to `"Hello World"` is saved for later execution.

Comment: So f indirectly reference to "Hello World"?

Comment: The JLS does not specify that the method reference stores the evaluation of `s`.  Only that a reference does get stored because of the method reference.

Comment: Can you explain me why this is different from my first example https://pastebin.com/MMSA2Bc9
because this isn't working

Comment: @user5327287 in the pastebin snippet `f` is an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) implementing the `Function<Integer, String>` interface. The rules for local variable captures are different for method references and anonymous classes. In anonymous classes all captured local variables must be declared  `final` or effectively final (only assigned once).

Answer (score 11):

Let's convert that method reference to a lambda and see what happens:

```
String s = "Hello World";
Function<Integer, String> f = i -> s.substring(i); // Doesn't compile!
s = null;
System.out.println(f.apply(5));
```

The above doesn't compile because `s` is being changed outside of the lambda, so it is not effectively final.  Therefore, we can deduce that using a method reference caches the value of `s` before it's actually used.

See: [Is method reference caching a good idea in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983832/is-method-reference-caching-a-good-idea-in-java-8)

Comment: I don't think that is is correct... if you remove the last `s = null` and decompile the generated classes, you will see that they *both* (lambda and method references) try to cache the value - it is a different story for a lambda because the rules of "anonymous class" apply

Comment: I thought it too, I tried to use annonymos class instead of method reference but it didn't work because I was needed to change "s" to final. This inferring is good for thinking but alot of times I deduce things in programing and somtimes I wasn't right.

Comment: @user5327287 exactly. using a lambda is like using an anonymous inner class, but using a method reference is not even close to that. More to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053161/1059372, to be honest, this is a duplicate of that

Answer (score 5):

> One more thing, why don't I need a return statement here?

When specifying only a single lambda statement, its value is automatically returned from the lambda.

```
Function<Integer, String> f = s::substring;
```

Java works with [pass-by-value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593867/4990642) So, `f` is a reference copy.

Comment: I always thought it by reference and not value.

Comment: @user5327287 the proof that it is by reference is that in a method parameter ```void c(String s)  {s = "xx"; }``` and you main like ```String s = "bb"; c(s); System.out.println(s);``` the value will still be 'bb' since non references was changed.