# Nulling variable does not invalidate method reference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, method-reference

Why does the code not throw a `NullPointerException` when I use a method reference tied to a variable `dog` which I later assigned `null` to?

I am using Java 8.

```java
import java.util.function.Function;

class Dog {
    private int food = 10;

    public int eat(int num) {
        System.out.println("eat " + num);
        this.food -= num;
        return this.food;
    }
}

public class MethodRefrenceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Function<Integer, Integer> function = dog::eat;

        dog = null;

        // I can still use the method reference
        System.out.println("still have " + function.apply(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is defined with the object `dog` is pointing at, it is not concerned with the `dog` variable itself.

Comment: if you call dog.something,   will throw the NullPointerException,  but your code not.

Comment: Related: [Why can method reference use non-final variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052917/why-can-method-reference-use-non-final-variables)

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514995/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lambda-and-a-method-reference-at-a-runtime-leve/33966159#33966159) this for another question. I don't think the question is a duplicate, though.

Comment: Also related [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: i think the key point is :
"When a method reference expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the :: separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. The result of evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional interface type is invoked;",

not " Java is “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”".  @Zabuza

Comment: The pass-by was more meant to be related in a sense that it explains the difference between variables and instances. That nulling a variables does not invalidate the instance, only the variable. Combine that with the more important fact (as others pointed out) that method references dont take your variable but the actual instance behind it. But yeah, thats why I only said related and not duplicate or anything. But the current linked duplicate is pretty good, with JLS excerpts.

Comment: Nonetheless, your question is a good contribution. Its well asked and the title is better than the duplicate, so people will likely find it when searching for similar problems.

Answer (score 6):

The `dog::eat` method reference captures the instance referenced by `dog`, so when you call `function.apply(2)`, the `eat` method is executed for that instance. It doesn't matter that the `dog` variable no longer references that instance.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `dog` used at the lambda expression is *visible* only at the scope of the lambda expression since its definition and nullifying the `dog` will not affect the method reference `dog::eat`.

An example without usage of `dog` with the same functionality:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> function = new Dog()::eat;
```