# Method reference does not always seem to capture instance

Tags: java, java-8, instance, functional-interface, supplier

I know there are many questions on the subject even a [very recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457483/nulling-variable-does-not-invalidate-method-reference) but I still can't work my head around one thing. Consider the following **functional interface**:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface PersonInterface {
    String getName();
}
```

And this implementation:

```
class Person implements PersonInterface {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If I look at these threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457483/nulling-variable-does-not-invalidate-method-reference) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622262/function-pointer-to-string-method-in-java), I expect the following code to output `"Bob"` and not throw a `NullPointerException` because as far as I understand, when I create my Supplier, it captures the `Person` instance.

```
Person p = new Person("Bob");
Supplier<String> f = p::getName;
p = null;
System.out.println(f.get());
```

And it correctly outputs `"Bob"`

Now what I do not understand is why the following code does not also output `"Bob"`?

```
Person p = new Person("Bob");
Supplier<String> f = p::getName;
p.setName("Alice");
System.out.println(f.get());
```

It actually outputs `"Alice"`

It seems to me that in the first example the lambda captured the state of the Person object when it was created and does not try to re-evaluate it when it is called, when in the second case, it seems like it did not capture it, but revaluates it when it is called.

**EDIT**
After re-reading the other threads and with Eran's answer, I wrote that bit with 2 Persons pointing to the same instance:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Bob");
Person p2 = p1;
Supplier<String> f1 = p1::getName;
Supplier<String> f2 = p2::getName;
p1 = null;
p2.setName("Alice");
System.out.println(f1.get());
System.out.println(f2.get());
```

Now I can see that they both output `"Alice"` even though p1 is null and therefore the method reference captured the instance itself, not its state as I wrongly assumed.

Comment: I think it would be weird/error-prone if you changed the name of the person (as in your code block) and didn't get back the updated value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems to me that in the first example the lambda captured the state of the Person object when it was created and does not try to re-evaluate it when it is called, when in the second case, it seems like it did not capture it, but revaluates it when it is called.

First of all, it's a method reference, not a lambda expression.

In both cases a reference to the `Person` instance is captured by the method reference (which is not "the state of the Person object"). That means that if the state of the `Person` instance is mutated, the result of executing the functional interface's method may change.

The method reference does not create a copy of the `Person` instance whose reference it captures.

Comment: I think I understand now, I just had the Eureka moment. I added an edit in my question with something I tried and that clears it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with lambdas or method references *in a way*, it's just side effects of these constructs that you are using.

For a much simpler reasoning you could think about it as:

```
static class SupplierHolder {
    private final Person p;
    // constructor/getter
}

static class Person {
    private String name;
    // constructor/getter/setter
}
```

When you create: `Supplier<String> f = p::getName;`, you can think about it as creating a `SupplierHolder` that takes a `Person` as input and has a method reference to its `getName`.

It's like doing:

```
Person p = new Person("Bob");
SupplierHolder sh = new SupplierHolder(p);
p = null; // this has no effect on the reference that SupplierHolder holds
System.out.println(sh.getPerson().getName());
```

In your second example, you have:

```
Person p = new Person("Bob");
SupplierHolder sh = new SupplierHolder(p); 
p.setName("Alice");
```

Now `p` reference and the reference that `SupplierHolder` holds, "act" on the same instance - they point to the same Object.

It's not exactly the same in reality, but proves the point, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now, I already accepted Eran's answer because it made me understand the point. Upvoted yours.